# How do u log in using the lexik bundle and jwt?

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I want to log in a user. I have already created the register controller. In the login controller we authenticate based on the password, the role, and the roleid. If logged generate a jwt token.  How do u do this?

**This is the authcontroller **

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Address;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Role;
use App\Entity\PersonInfo;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
class RegistersController extends AbstractController 
{


    public function __construct(protected EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, protected ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
    }
    /**
 * @param string $message
 * @param array $data
 * @param int $status
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
protected function respondWithSuccess(string $message, array $data = [], int $status = JsonResponse::HTTP_OK): JsonResponse
{
    $responseData = [
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message,
        'data' => $data,
    ];

    return new JsonResponse($responseData, $status);
}
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    #[Route('/register-role', name: 'register_role')]
    public function registerRole(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
    {
        $requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        
        //Create new Address entity
        $address = new Address();
        $address->setStreet($requestData['street']);
        $address->setHouseNumber($requestData['house_number']);
        $address->setPostalCode($requestData['postal_code']);
        $address->setCity($requestData['city']);
        $address->setProvince($requestData['province']);

       
    
         //Create new PersonInfo entity
         $personinfo = new PersonInfo();
         $personinfo->setName($requestData['first_name']);
         $personinfo->setEmail($requestData['email']);
         $personinfo->setPhoneNumber($requestData['phone_number']);
    
        // Create new Role entity
        $role = new Role($this->validator);
        $role->setName($requestData['role_name']);
        
       
        // Create new User entity
        $user = new User();
        $password = $requestData['password'];
        $hashedPassword = $passwordHasher->hashPassword(
            $user,
            $password
        );
        $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);
        $user->setRoleId($role);
    
        // Persist entities
        $this->entityManager->persist($address);
        $this->entityManager->persist($personinfo);
        $this->entityManager->persist($role);
    
        // Set the PersonInfo object in the User entity
        $personinfo->setUser($user);
    
        // Persist and flush User entity
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        
        
        return new Response('Signed up successfully');

    }

    /**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @param JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTManager
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    #[Route('/login',name: 'login', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function getTokenUser(UserInterface $user, JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTManager): JsonResponse
    {
            return $this->respondWithSuccess('Signed in successfully', ['token' => $JWTManager->create($user)]);
       
    }
}
?>
```

I tried making my own login function but that didnt work, because the password is hashed in the database, but it didnt compare using the password_verify() function.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here in the documentation :
https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/index.html https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

you do not have to create this logic yourself, just define a firewall.
Something like this :

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

Then if you do :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost/api/login_check -d '{"username":"johndoe","password":"test"}'
```

You should get a token.

The user provider will find the registered user for you from the id and password,
see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html

And to check the restrictions on the role : you can use a voter. Also, in term of cleanliness, authentication and role permissions should be separated because they are two differents steps.

Comment: Thanks, but is not working. i get the error {"code":401,"message":"Invalid credentials."}% even tho my credentials are right. It can also not find this Undefined type 'Lexik\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface'.